# Woo-commerce add to cart button missing. (yep, another one)

Tags: java, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the problem that with merchandise where there multiple options (t-shirt sizes, etc) that the 'add to cart' button is missing. It is  OK where there there is only one option - a cd for example. I have entered all the info, stock numbers, prices, etc.

The problem persists if I turn off all other plugins. I can't see an error in the Java console (I tried a plugin that is supposed to fix java errors anyway) and the add to cart button is visible if I switch to another theme. Be great of someone who has been down this path can get me started on finding a solution.

Thanks for you help!

`http://5.133.182.68/~knifewor/product/knifeworld-gold-logo-t-shirt/`

Update

Turning debugging on I can see the following error:

```
Notice: wp_enqueue_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in /home/knifewor/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3245

Notice: wp_enqueue_style was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in /home/knifewor/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3245

Notice: Cookie cannot be set - headers already sent in /home/knifewor/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php on line 375

Notice: Cookie cannot be set - headers already sent in /home/knifewor/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php on line 375

Notice: Cookie cannot be set - headers already sent in /home/knifewor/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php on line 375
```

And I now notice on the shop page the footer fails to load.

Comment: This [Link](http://develop.woothemes.com/woocommerce/2014/02/solving-common-issues-after-updating-to-woocommerce-2-1/) may be useful to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a php error in the page. You need to turn on the WP_DEBUG to see the error.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, if the problem goes away when you switch themes, especially if there's no JS error, then we can assume the problem is in your theme's WooCommerce templates. They are probably out of date. I fixed a lot of themes that "broke" when WooCommerce updated to 2.0/2.1.

In the admin, under WooCommerce go to System Settings and at the bottom of the page you should see any templates that are being overridden in the theme. I *think* it should also say which templates are out of date.

If you `view source` you will see the page is incompletely loaded. This means `wp_footer()` is never run and therefore all the scripts that belong in the footer are never loaded... including WooCommerce's add to cart scripts.

Therefore, I second @sabanix's answer to turn on `WP_DEBUG`. The problem may or may not be in your theme's WooCommerce templates, or a more generic error in your theme.

If I had to guess, it is probably `single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php` template. I would suggest renaming it (or deleting it) so that WooCommerce will use its default template and see if that resolves it.

Comment: Thanks for that. Seems there is an error in the template code. Ive contacted the auther and I'm waiting on a fix.

Thanks!

Comment: Sure. Remember you can disable the theme's WooCommerce templates by renaming/deleting them. If you rename the woocommerce folder in your theme your site will probably come back to life, though with default Woo markup.

Comment: They are still to come back to me - a pain as it is holding up a launch. According to woocommerce/system status there are no template overrides. However one thing is clear and that is the footer is indeed failing to load..

Comment: And you confirm that you definitely don't have a `woocommerce` folder in your theme? The notices you posted in you update shouldn't break the site... only fatal errors do that.

Comment: Assuming that the problem goes away if you switch to Twenty Fourteen, the next place would be `single-product.php` in the theme's folder. But since the `#left-area` div is the last thing to render you know the problem is in whatever comes immediately after that.

Comment: You continue to give me your time and good advice - thank you!